# What to do about a plagiarized post?

Tags: support, etiquette, policy

I recently noticed that a user has copied one my posts without crediting me. Who do I contact here about this and how?

Comment: Damn you for knowing better than to say who he is.

Comment: @GitGud haha thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flag the (alleged) plagiarism for moderator attention using the "other" reason

[image: "Other" flag an answer]

explaining what the problem is and linking to the post of yours that you think was copied. A moderator will look into the situation and determine what should be done.

Comment: Thank you very much.